# php composer install or NOT? for production environments

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am working on Laravel webapp right now and kept `vendor` directory out of git (version control) so far and every time for fresh install I used to have composer install command added to automated script and everything was fine.

Now just 2 days back I added added laravelcollective (https://laravelcollective.com/) to my project for helping me with forms and html in blade templates. Now somehow one of the dependency requires me to generate GIT private token to install it and that is pain as it would hurt my automation. I can still hack it by calling the url and scrapping html to read token and stuff like that but I don't like it. And then I thought is it good idea to keep `vendor` directory out of SVN/GIT? Isn't source code for a product contain all dependencies within itself? I am not talking about stuffing JRE in the installer but when it comes to libraries of a product in native language.

I would like to hear more about it on industry standards or best practices on this.

P.S:
This question is much generic and not just limited to laravel or even php for the matter.

Comment: "Isn't source code for a product contain all dependencies within itself?" - All the dependencies are listed and people who use your code will know what is needed, it's unecessary to add a lot of extra code to your version control when people can just get the same code by running `composer update`

Comment: composer has it's benefits but what is the solution when you're trying to automate the build process and get hit by some library/plugin which requires you to go and generate access token?

Comment: I've never encountered that before, what library are you talking about?

Comment: There's no reason you can't generate a Github (not Git) token and put it into your build automation scripts/process. We do exactly that at my job.

Comment: see Deploy keys https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/ and Creating an access token for command-line use https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/ will fulfill ur needs :)

Comment: @aimme Deploy keys aren't the solution here. OP has run into a (common) issue of downloading many packages from Github without being authenticated, which triggers rate limiting. Composer's documentation notes the (trivially easy) solution here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens (`composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`)

Comment: @ceejayoz so that means the second one

Answer (score 2):

> Now somehow one of the dependency requires me to generate GIT private token to install it and that is pain as it would hurt my automation.

You're just running into Github's rate limits for package downloads for anonymous users. No reason you can't automate this. Generate a Github token (you only need to do it once - they get *very* high rate limits for authenticated requests), then have your automation use that token like so:

> `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens

Answer (score 1):

Well, for production environment you usually run a build process first in your CI software. If 'composer install' fails during the build – application won't be deployed to production environment, so you are safe.

Yes, most (99%+) people keep 'vendor' folder out of the repo because it's a third-party code, it's not yours. You may not even have rights to host it in your repo.

If you want to be sure that your production version will have all the dependencies in order, the way you had them during CI, and will always release – you could build Docker images and ship them to production. Then, everything comes prepackaged.